# SPI based 16 channel TLC59282DBQR LED DRIVER with raspberry pi 4b

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi4

I want to Drive led connected to ch0 of TLC59282DBQR(LED driver) with 100% brightness or at least turn ON LED.
I'm trying to use the 16-channel, TLC59282DBQR constant-current sink LED Driver with an SPI interface. I want to know how to check SPI is correctly interface between raspberry pi 4b and led driver. The problem is, I can't convince the board to produce any meaningful output. All I get is a dirty ground signal on all channels. I probe the outputs directly with a oscilloscope, nothing else connected.

For[Datasheet of TLC59282DBQR LED DRIVER](https://www.ti.com/product/TLC59281/part-details/TLC59281DBQR)

Connections made between the SPI based led driver IC and the PI are:
LED driver Raspberry pi
SIN(MOSI) MOSI(GPIO10)
SOUT(MISO) MISO(GPIO9)
SCLK SCLK(GPIO11)
LAT GPIO22
BLANK GPIO0

I am trying to run following code to just drive led with 100% brightness..

```
"use strict";
// Drive ch0 of TLC59281
const TLC59281DBQR = require("../tlc59281dbqr.js");

const SPI_CHANNEL = "/dev/spidev0.0";
const PIN_LATCH = 15;
const PIN_BLANK= 0;
const ledDriver = new TLC59281DBQR(SPI_CHANNEL, PIN_LATCH, PIN_BLANK, 1000 /* 1000Hz=1kHz */);
ledDriver.start();

ledDriver.selectChannel(0);
ledDriver.setDuty(1.0); // 100% drive
```

## when i try to run above code with given connection my code is run without error but LED on set with 100% brightness.

here ("../tlc59281dbqr.js") file

```
// TLC59281DBQR
"use strict";
const SPI = require('pi-spi');
const rpio = require('rpio');
const raspi = require('raspi');
const pwm = require('raspi-pwm');

/*
  SPI channel example: "/dev/spidev0.0"
*/ 
class TLC59281DBQR {
  constructor (spi /* Channel name (string) or pi-spi object */, pinLatch, pinBlank, blankFrequency) {
    this.pinLatch = pinLatch;
    this.pinBlank = pinBlank;
    this.useBlankPWM = pinBlank > 0;
    if (!this.useBlankPWM) {
      console.log("Blank PWM is disabled.");
    }
    
    console.log("TLC59281DBQR.constructor");
    this.spi = null;
    if (typeof(spi)=='string') {
      this.spiCh = spi;
    } else if (spi != null) {
      this.spi = spi;
    } else {
      console.error("constructor spi is not specified. Please pass a SPI obect or channel name.");
    }
    this.blankFrequency = blankFrequency;
    rpio.open(this.pinLatch, rpio.OUTPUT, rpio.LOW);
  }
  start () {
    console.log("TLC59281DBQR.start");
    if (this.spi == null) {
      this.spi = SPI.initialize(this.spiCh);
    }
    if (this.useBlankPWM) {
      this.blank = new pwm.PWM({pin:this.pinBlank, frequency:this.blankFrequency}); 
    }
  }
  selectChannel (ch) {
    const buffVal = 0x0001 << ch;
    const lower = 0xFF & buffVal;
    const upper = 0xFF & (buffVal >> 8);
    this.spi.write(new Buffer([upper, lower]), ()=>{
      // Latch pulse
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.HIGH);
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.LOW);
    });
  }
  onAll () {
    this.spi.write(new Buffer([0xFF, 0xFF]), ()=>{
      // Latch pulse
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.HIGH);
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.LOW);
    });
  }
  offAll () {
    this.spi.write(new Buffer([0x00, 0x00]), ()=>{
      // Latch pulse
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.HIGH);
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.LOW);
    });
  }
  setDuty (val) {
    if (this.useBlankPWM) {
      this.blank.write(val);
    }
  }
  off () {
    this.spi.write(new Buffer([0x00, 0x00]), ()=>{
      // Latch pulse
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.HIGH);
      rpio.write(this.pinLatch, rpio.LOW);
    });
  }
}
module.exports = TLC59281DBQR;
```

====================================================================================================
when i run the code without any error code run perfectly . so i am getting where is actual problem why led not turn ON.
first i want to know my connection and setup is correct. How to check the spi communication between pi and led driver is set up or not.

please help me to drive my led with led driver and pi.

Any help highly appreciated! Thanks :)

I am trying to drive led connected to ch0 of led driver with 100% brightness but i am not getting any output. The led driver TLC59281DBQR and raspberry pi 4b i am using . The led driver and raspberry pi communicate through SPI communication.